# Как ждать сообщение от пользователя telegram bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть telegram bot.
Есть условие, если клиент написал "Привет" бот скидывает клиенту сообщения "Напишите ваше имя". Вопрос такой, как ждать и получить следующие сообщение от клиента боту поле того как клиент написал "Привет".

```
if ($update["message"]["text"] == "Привет") {
$msg = "Напишите ваше имя";
$sendto ="https://api.telegram.org/bot$botToken/sendmessage?parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".urlencode($msg)."&disable_web_page_preview=true&reply_markup=".json_encode($replyMarkup);
    file_get_contents($sendto);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Непонятен вопрос. Все новые сообщения будут в $update["message"], получаете так же как и "Привет", а обрабатываете так как вам необходимо...

Comment: @IvanChaykin $update["message"] это динамическая переменная.

Comment: Так оно и есть, $update["message"] это динамическая переменная. Если вы ждёте конкретное сообщение то обрабатываете его так же как и "Привет" `if ($update["message"]["text"] == "Сообщение") {...}`. Уточните ваш вопрос.

Comment: Нужно условие после конкретного сообщения, то есть - клиент пишет "Привет", бот отправляет клиенту "Напишите ваше имя" дальше клиент пишет свое имя допустим "Влад" - это сообщение и нужно взять и занести в переменную.

Comment: Можно в базе данных хранить состояние для каждого chat_id, и в зависимости от состояния, обрабатывать сообщение уже как ответ. Либо требовать префикс перед именем, например "name Влад" и отрлавливать ответ по "name"